# I want to save objects on the scene like Minecraft

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, minecraft

In Minecraft, the location of a lot of block are saved.

I will try it in my own way by using PlayerPrefs.

```
int i, ObjectType;
Vector3 Pos;

// ObjectType is a block ID such as grass block or iron block in Minecraft.
// Pos is a position of each blocks

PlayerPrefs.SetString("object" + i, ObjectType + ", " + Pos);
```

However, when handling hundreds of data, it was said that PlayerPrefs can not be recommended.I only know the saving of data in PlayerPrefs.

What should I do in such cases?

Comment: `it was said that PlayerPrefs can not be recommended` What does that mean? **Who** didn't recommend it?

Comment: I watched an article on the website saying that running a lot of PlayerPrefs at the same time would put a big burden on the system.

Comment: One thing you may be interested in knowing is that minecraft uses procedural generation and only saves the *changes* you make.

Comment: you should rather use e.g. an `Xml`, `JSON` or `Csv` file depending on your data

Comment: Xml, JSON or Csv are other types good for saving data. You should just keep in mind these types are easy to modify on client devices.

Answer (score 2):

PlayerPrefs are meant to store and accesses player preferences between game sessions like settings. You can only use it to save string, int or float data types. Yes, it should not be used for storing a lot of data like you want. What if you decide to add more levels? You will end up with all levels, settings and other game information in one PlayerPrefs dictionary object which is hard to maintain, inefficient and easy to modify by your users.

You should make a class/struct with information about a level, list of block objects etc. and then serialize the object into binary which can be saved on a local device as a file or streamed to an online server. I suggest to watch this Unity Live Session tutorial: [Persistence - Saving and Loading Data](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data) for beginners.

You can also store your game data in a database locally or online.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to rather use e.g. an `XML` file to store all the structure of your data

**Block**: For storing the data of one block. You can extend this at wish forexample with a `BlockType` enum or a material color etc (anything that is serializable)

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class Block
{
    [XmlAttribute] public string Name;
    [XmlElement] public Vector3 Position;

    // for the serializer a parameter-free default constructor is mandatory
    public Block() { }

    public Block(string name, Vector3 position)
    {
        Name = name;
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

**BlocksData**: For storing the data of all blocks and handling XML file IO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

[XmlRoot("BlocksData")]
[Serializable]
public class BlocksData
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Block> Blocks = new List<Block>();

    public void Save(string filePath)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BlocksData));
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }

    public static BlocksData Load(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("File not found: " + filePath);
        }

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BlocksData));
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as BlocksData;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally a controller class that uses this `BlocksData` and does something with it. E.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class BlocksController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string FILE_EXTENSION = ".xml";

    // fileName of the XML file (without extension)
    public string FileName;

    // prefab to be spawned for each block
    public GameObject BlockPrefab;

    // blocks in the scene
    public List<Transform> SceneBlocks;

    // blocks in the data
    public BlocksData BlocksData;

    private static string Folder
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            return Application.streamingAssetsPath;
#else
            return Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
        }
    }

    private string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Folder, FileName + FILE_EXTENSION);

        }
    }

    [ContextMenu("Load Blocks")]
    public void LoadBlocks()
    {
        // Load from file
        BlocksData = BlocksData.Load(FilePath);

        // remove current scene blocks
        foreach (var sceneBlock in SceneBlocks)
        {
            // Have to se destroyImmediate in editmode
            if (Application.isEditor && !Application.isPlaying)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(sceneBlock.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(sceneBlock.gameObject);
            }
        }

        // instantiate and setup prefab foreach block in data
        foreach (var block in BlocksData.Blocks)
        {
            var newBlock = Instantiate(BlockPrefab, block.Position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            newBlock.name = block.Name;

            // don't forget to add it to the list of sceneBlocks
            SceneBlocks.Add(newBlock.transform);
        }
    }

    [ContextMenu("Save Blocks")]
    public void SaveBlocks()
    {
        // clear current data list
        BlocksData.Blocks.Clear();

        // add a block data foreach block in scene
        foreach (var sceneBlock in SceneBlocks)
        {
            BlocksData.Blocks.Add(new Block(sceneBlock.name, sceneBlock.position));
        }

        // finally write to file
        BlocksData.Save(FilePath);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif
    }
}
```

see [Saving and Loading Data: XmlSerializer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) for more details.